# Appium session does not exist error after upgrade to latest version

Tags: ios, xcode, appium, appium-ios, ios-ui-automation

So i have `MAC` and real `iPhone` device connected (`IOS 12.2`).

From another computer I start the driver and perform my stuff.

Today after upgrade `appium` version I got this `error`:

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: Session
> does not exist

And my suspicion is the upgrade.

What could change after this upgrade (location...) ?

Comment: So it is appium 1.12.1, you want to say?